# Can we unlock the achievement twice in google game centre

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have implemented unlocking achievements , but I am fetcing the user details and then unlocking all achievements when ever user visited my activity , each time when we requested achievement which is already unlocked for the user is unlocked twice , is it a right way to unlock an achievement twice or more , is there any consequences in doing this please let me know !

How do we get the unlocked achievements , before unlocking an achievement  I need to get the status of the achievement whether is unlocked or not , how can we achieve this ?

Comment: No an achievement cannot be unlocked twice

Comment: Then , how do we get the all the unlocked achievements ids which are unlocked

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Quests](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/quests) as a solution.  This allows you to define events within your game that are used to complete the quest.  Quests can be configured to be repeatable (weekly or monthly) so the quest state will be automatically reset for the player.

Depending on your needs, you might be able to do something clever like have 7 quests that repeat weekly so you can track the day of the week...

Comment: How do we get the unlocked achievements , before unlocking an achievement  I need to get the status of the achievement whether is unlocked or not , how can we achieve this ?

Comment: You can call Games.Achievements.load() https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#load(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, boolean)  to load all the achievements then check the state.  But it is completely OK to unlock an unlocked achievement.